# Unexpected local shell in TRAMP mode

Tags: spacemacs, tramp, shell

I have a clear installation of spacemacs with layer shell on.

1. I open remote dir `SPC f f ssh:<host>:<path>`
2. I open shell `SPC '`
3. Shell is local (I expect it to be opened on the remote host)

Comment: `ssh:<host>:<path>` is wrong, it misses the leading slash like in `/ssh:<host>:<path>`

Comment: yes, you are right, I wrote my input, and emacs fills in `/`. Still it doesn't matter, cause it works, I get dired opened on remote machine

Comment: Then I don't understand the rest of your complaint. Could you, please, give a recipe, starting with `emacs -Q`

Comment: I guess the problem occurs in spacemacs. I tried `emacs -Q` and shell opened correctly on remote